# In general, what is the rank of a differential form?

Tags: differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, matrix-rank, symplectic-linear-algebra, tensor-rank

This is a general question about ranks of differential forms.

I read in a book the phrase "symplectic form has constant rank..."  I understand that the symplectic form is a nondegenerate differential 2-form.  But what is the rank of a symplectic form?

In general, what is the rank of a differential form?  When I think rank, I think about the dimension of the range of a matrix.  Is there some matrix associated with a differential form?  Or does rank in this context refer to tensor rank?

I also understand the notion of the rank of a differentiable map between manifolds.  If $f:M \rightarrow N$ is differentiable and $p\in M$, the rank is the dimension of the image of the derivative:

$\mathrm{rank}(f)_p = \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{image}(df_p))$,

where $df_p:T_p M \rightarrow T_{f(p)} N$.

Comment: You should be getting an alternating bilinear form on each tangent space; it makes sense to ask for the rank of that. Just linear algebra, hopefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any two-form gives a (skew-symmetric) bilinear form $TM_p \times TM_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

The rank of the two-form at $p$ is the rank of this bilinear form.

*What's the rank of a bilinear form?*

A bilinear map $B: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to a linear map $V \rightarrow V^*$ given by $v \mapsto B(v,\cdot)$. The rank of this linear map is the rank of the bilinear form.

---

Some further comments: Non-degenerate means full rank, i.e. that the linear maps $TM_p \rightarrow TM^*_p$ you get are isomorphisms. So a symplectic form is always constant rank.

Comment: The full phrase in the book I'm reading is: "the restriction of the symplectic form to $N$ ($N$ is a submanifold of the symplectic manifold) has constant rank in a neighborhood of a point"....Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, what that means is you restrict (aka pullback via the inclusion) the symplectic form to the submanifold $N$. Now you have a two-form on $N$, which need not be symplectic. The book is asserting that in the situation in the book, the restriction has constant rank in the neighborhood (in $N$) of some point (this isn't true for an arbitrary submanifold and point so there's some extra condition, or maybe the book's asserting there exists a point s.t. it's constant rank in the neighborhood of that point).